# Carousel Using Vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, api, event-handling, dom

As a beginner project, I've start working on this carousel slider that would slide through an image and a testimonial on click.

The number of images and content slides would always be the same number. I got the javascript to work but I feel like I'm repeating myself on some of my helper classes. I've tried to rework them so I could use some higher order function to achieve what I'm trying to do but I haven't had any luck. If anyone could review this or point me in the right direction that would be great.

JSFiddle Link here: https://jsfiddle.net/ej87pdsb/

```js
// CAROUSEL GALLERY
const carouselBtns = document.querySelectorAll(`[class*='arr-']`);
const carouselImages = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-images img'));
const carouselContent = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-content .carousel-content-item'));
let currentSlide = 0;

function activateSlider(e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('arr-next')) {
        arrNextBtn();
    } else {
        arrPrevBtn();
    }
}

function arrNextBtn() {
    if (currentSlide == carouselImages.length - 1) {
        currentSlide = 0;
    } else {
        currentSlide++;
    }
    addRemoveHideClass();
}

function arrPrevBtn() {
    if (currentSlide == 0) {
        currentSlide = carouselImages.length - 1;
    } else {
        currentSlide--;
    }
    addRemoveHideClass();
}

function addRemoveHideClass() {
    carouselImages.filter(function (img) {
        if (img == foundImage()) {
            img.classList.remove('hide');
        } else {
            img.classList.add('hide');
        }
    });
    carouselContent.filter(function (content) {
        if (content == foundContent()) {
            content.classList.remove('hide');
        } else {
            content.classList.add('hide');
        }
    });
}

function foundImage() {
    const imageMatch = carouselImages.find(function findMatchingImage(img, index) {
        if (index == currentSlide) {
            return img;
        }
    });
    return imageMatch;
}

function foundContent() {
    const contentMatch = carouselContent.find(function findMatchingContent(content, index) {
        if (index == currentSlide) {
            return content;
        }
    });
    return contentMatch;
}

carouselBtns.forEach(function (btn) {
    btn.addEventListener('click', activateSlider);
});
```

```css
/* RESET STUFF */
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}


/** FLEX / POSITIONING ON MOBILE **/
.carousel {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

/* Previous and Next Arrow Positioning */
.carousel-arrs [class*='arr-'] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 37%;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.carousel-arrs .arr-prev {
    left: -2%;
}

.carousel-arrs .arr-next {
    right: -2%;
}

/** SETTING SCROLLING CONTENT INLINE, HIDDING OVERFLOWS AND SETTING HEIGHTS AND WIDTHS FOR MAIN CONTENT SECTIONS **/
.carousel-content,
.carousel-images {
    display: inline-flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  width:100%;
}

.carousel-content {
    height: 450px;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.carousel-images img {
    width: 100vw;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 310px;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 0.25rem 0.25rem 0% 0%; /* Rem Values Taken from BS4 .rounded class*/
}

.carousel-content-item {
  min-width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 40px;
}

/** MOBILE / TYPOGRAPHY / PADDING / MARGINS STYLING **/

.carousel {
  border-radius: .25rem!important;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    box-shadow: 0 50px 100px -20px rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25),
        0 30px 60px -30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3),
        inset 0 -2px 6px 0 rgba(10, 37, 64, 0.35);
}

.carousel-arrs [class*='arr-'] svg {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #00aeef;
    box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.105);
    transition: cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
    pointer-events: all;
}

.carousel-arrs [class*='arr-'] svg:hover {
    color: #f4af38;
    transform: translateY(-2px);
}

/* Transitions and Hide Class Styling */
.carousel-images img, .carousel-content .carousel-content-item {
    transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.3s ease-in;
}

.hide {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

/** STYLE OVERRIDES FOR 768PX AND ABOVE  **/
@media (min-width: 768px) {

  /** FLEX / POSITIONING **/

    .carousel {
        flex-flow: row nowrap;
    align-items: stretch;
    overflow:hidden;
  }

  /* Previous and Next Arrow Positioning */
    .carousel-arrs [class*='arr-'] {
        top: 50%;
  }

    .carousel-arrs .arr-prev {
        left: 0%;
    }
    .carousel-arrs .arr-next {
        right: 0%;
  }

  /* SETTING SCROLLING CONTENT INLINE, HIDDING OVERFLOWS AND SETTING HEIGHTS AND WIDTHS FOR MAIN CONTENT SECTIONS */
  .carousel-content {
        height: 550px;
        align-items: center;
  }

  .carousel .carousel-images,
    .carousel .carousel-content {
        flex-basis: 50%;
    }

  /** MOBILE / TYPOGRAPHY / PADDING / MARGINS STYLING **/
    .carousel-images {
        background-color: #00afef44;
        -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 78% 100%, 0% 100%);
        clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 78% 100%, 0% 100%);
    }
    .carousel-images img {
        min-height: 100%;
        -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
        clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
  }

    .carousel-content-item {
        padding: 80px 70px 80px 0px;
    }
}
```

```html
<section class="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-arrs">
    <button class="arr-prev">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50" fill="currentColor"
        class="bi bi-arrow-left-circle-fill " viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path
          d="M8 0a8 8 0 1 0 0 16A8 8 0 0 0 8 0zm3.5 7.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H5.707l2.147 2.146a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708l-3-3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708l3-3a.5.5 0 1 1 .708.708L5.707 7.5H11.5z" />
      </svg>
    </button>
    <button class="arr-next"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50" fill="currentColor"
        class="bi bi-arrow-right-circle-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path
          d="M8 0a8 8 0 1 1 0 16A8 8 0 0 1 8 0zM4.5 7.5a.5.5 0 0 0 0 1h5.793l-2.147 2.146a.5.5 0 0 0 .708.708l3-3a.5.5 0 0 0 0-.708l-3-3a.5.5 0 1 0-.708.708L10.293 7.5H4.5z" />
      </svg></button>
  </div>

  <div class="carousel-images">
    <img src="https://stripe.com/img/v3/atlas_v2/user_photos/metafused.jpg" class="img-fluid center-block carousel-img" alt="">
    <img src="https://stripe.com/img/v3/atlas_v2/user_photos/sheleadsafrica.jpg" class="img-fluid center-block carousel-img"
      alt="">
    <img src="https://stripe.com/img/v3/atlas_v2/user_photos/coin_tracker.jpg" class="img-fluid center-block carousel-img"
      alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="carousel-content">
    <div class="carousel-content-item">
      
      <p class="font-weight-light h3 text-muted font-italic">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam neque modi dolorem incidunt voluptatibus nostrum quae quo ad perferendis accusamus!
      </p>
      <p><strong class="h4">TEST
        </strong> <br>
TEST          </p>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-content-item">
     
      <p class="font-weight-light h3 text-muted font-italic">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum dolor tempore rerum est temporibus, amet cum. Quos distinctio impedit ipsum.</p>
      <p><strong class="h4">test</strong> <br>
        test Lorem, ipsum dolor.

      </p>

    </div>
    <div class="carousel-content-item">
      
      <p class="font-weight-light h3 text-muted font-italic">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam distinctio omnis odio dicta ad maiores accusantium voluptatibus cum nemo expedita?</p>
      <p><strong class="h4">test</strong> <br>
        test Lorem, ipsum dolor.

      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `addRemoveHideClass()` uses to calls to the array method `filter()`. That method "**creates a new array** with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function." <sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)</sup> That method is meant to filter an array of elements that match a certain criteria so it returns an array <sup>[2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#return_value)</sup>. If you just want to iterate over the elements in the array, you can use use [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), or a [`for...of` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop could be used instead. Also, each iteration of those loops calls `foundImage()` and `foundContent()`. This is quite inefficient. It would be more efficient to store the value of those calls outside the loop and use the stored value inside the loop.